# producer consumer model like scenario is not working

Tags: java, producer-consumer, timertask

This is the scenario. I have to poll a ftp server in a timed interval and get the csv files. Then these CSV files has to be parsed and send as a input to some business logic. I have done it in this way.

**FTPClientPolling** (Producer)

```
public class FTPClientPolling {

    private static FTPClientPolling instance = null;

    private FTPClientPolling() {
    }

    public synchronized static FTPClientPolling getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            logger.info("Object created for Client Polling");
            instance = new FTPClientPolling();
            initializeFTPClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void initializeFTPClient() {
        // initialize the values from properties file
    }

    public void startPolling() {

        FTPClient ftpClient = null;
        try {
            //connecting to ftp server

            //iterating the files in it
            FTPFile[] filesList = ftpClient.listFiles();
            for (FTPFile tmpFile : filesList) {
                //..
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile(tmpFile.getName(), null);
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                ftpClient.retrieveFile(tmpFile.getName(), fileOut);

                //adding the file to the Queue of the file processor
                FileProcessor.getInstance().getFilesToBeProcessedQueue().add(tempFile);
            }

            if (ftpClient.isConnected())
                ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logging
        } finally {
            //closing ftpclient
        }

    }
}
```

**FTPClientPollingTasker** (Producer Tasker)

```
public class FTPClientTasker extends TimerTask {
    private static Long timeInterval = 10000l;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FTPClientPolling.getInstance().startPolling();
    }

    public static void start() {
        TimerTask timerTask = new FTPClientTasker();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, timeInterval, timeInterval);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }
}
```

**FileProcessor** (Consumer)

```
public final class FileProcessor {

    private static FileProcessor instance = null;
    private Queue<File> filesToBeProcessedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<File>(10);

    private FileProcessor() {
    }

    public synchronized static FileProcessor getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FileProcessor();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!filesToBeProcessedQueue.isEmpty()) {
            processSyncFiles(filesToBeProcessedQueue.poll());
        }
    }

    private void processSyncFiles(File inputFile) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, Boolean> outputConsolidation = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
            List<InputBean> csvContentsList = CSVParser.readContentsFromCSV(fileReader, new InputBean());
            for (InputBean inputBean : csvContentsList) {
                boolean output = false;
                // some business logic
                outputConsolidation.put(inputBean.toString(), output);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logging
        }
    }

    public synchronized Queue<File> getFilesToBeProcessedQueue() {
        return filesToBeProcessedQueue;
    }
}
```

**FileProcessor Tasker** (Consumer Scheduler)
This class creates a Tasker for FileProcessor and runs it in a scheduled interval.

```
public final class FileProcessorTasker extends TimerTask {

    private static Long timeInterval = 5000l;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileProcessor.getInstance().run();
    }

    public static void start() {
        TimerTask timerTask = new FileProcessorTasker();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, timeInterval, timeInterval);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileProcessorTasker.start();
    }
}
```

Both the programs are working well individually. But when linked together through the `filesToBeProcessedQueue` it doesn't seems to be working.
The problem is `FTPClientPolling` creates an object of `FileProcessor` and adds the file to the Queue. **But** `FileProcessorTasker` creates another object of `FileProcessor` which has queue size as zero. This two different objects is the problem. How is it creating two objects, when the class is a `singleton`. Am I missing something in the singleton implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Don't use `Timer` and `TimerTask`. Use a `ExecutorService` for multi-threading.

And Use Eager Initialization in your Singleton classes. Or double checked locking of null in order to make you Singleton really singleton.

**FTPClientPolling.java**

```
public class FTPClientPolling {

    private static FTPClientPolling instance = new FTPClientPolling();

    private FTPClientPolling() {
        logger.info("Object created for Client Polling");
        initializeFTPClient();
    }

    public static FTPClientPolling getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void initializeFTPClient() {
        // initialize the values from properties file
    }

    public void startPolling() {

        FTPClient ftpClient = null;
        try {
            //connecting to ftp server

            //iterating the files in it
            FTPFile[] filesList = ftpClient.listFiles();
            for (FTPFile tmpFile : filesList) {
                //..
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile(tmpFile.getName(), null);
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                ftpClient.retrieveFile(tmpFile.getName(), fileOut);

                //adding the file to the Queue of the file processor
                FileProcessor.getInstance().getFilesToBeProcessedQueue().add(tempFile);
            }

            if (ftpClient.isConnected())
                ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logging
        } finally {
            //closing ftpclient
        }

    }
}
```

**FileProcessor.java**

```
public final class FileProcessor {

    private static FileProcessor instance = new FileProcessor();
    private Queue<File> filesToBeProcessedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<File>(10);

    private FileProcessor() {
    }

    public static FileProcessor getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!filesToBeProcessedQueue.isEmpty()) {
            processSyncFiles(filesToBeProcessedQueue.poll());
        }
    }

    private void processSyncFiles(File inputFile) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, Boolean> outputConsolidation = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
            List<InputBean> csvContentsList = CSVParser.readContentsFromCSV(fileReader, new InputBean());
            for (InputBean inputBean : csvContentsList) {
                boolean output = false;
                // some business logic
                outputConsolidation.put(inputBean.toString(), output);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logging
        }
    }

    public synchronized Queue<File> getFilesToBeProcessedQueue() {
        return filesToBeProcessedQueue;
    }
}
```

Read this [post](https://dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern-%E2%80%93) for more information.